# free a file used by others process in c#

Tags: c#, winapi, file-io, process

I would like in a software to log:
which processes are accessing a file
and
how to force free file from access by others processes (is it possible with API window?)
notice that you are enable to open a file with notepad and delete this file in disk without kill notepad.but for other program like word excel it is not possible. so there some program that lock resource other no.It means you can free but how? secondly it is possible that for some process they crash when you free but in my case it was only custom services that access those files 
Thank you

Comment: Don't know about the exact details, but wouldn't that seem like something very dangerous to allow?

Comment: I don't think you can free a file. You would have to kill the process that is holding it.

Comment: because files I talk about can be accessed only by custom service there is no mistake. Other services have their try catch IOException ;-) what i want isn't kill the other process only free file accessed

Comment: @nunespascal you will notice that you are enable to open a file with notepad and delete this file in disk without kill notepad.but for other program like word excel it is not possible. so there some program that lock resource other no.It means you can free but how? secondly it is possible that for some process they crash when you free but in my case it was only custom services that access those files

Comment: Yes, that depends on what lock the application acquires while opening the file. If it is your program that has the locks, why not open files with shared locks?

Comment: This is an unbelievably bad idea.

Comment: it is a service that stop all other project services that write in a log.Why? Because this service want to clean folder so it will destroy file (i have no need anymore of that file).Moreover, i don't want to query all project service to rewrite their way to log to not have a lock

Answer (score 1):

Please look at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/37dc9843-2583-41fc-8260-b78183aa4bed/

This might be of some help.